# Why We Need To Know About Hyperboles

Tags: word-usage, figurative, hyperbole

So I realize that hyperboles exist, but in school we're taught about them as if they are truly important to what we are going to be doing in life. I realize their usefulness, but why do we need to learn about them? There are plenty of people in this world using them without realizing it. Is there a reasoning behind us needing to know about hyperboles?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking why you need to know about "hyperbole", which cannot be plural, which is the use of exaggeration? Or are you asking about hyperbolas, which are a kind of math curve? The first should be obvious: you need to know about hyperbole because people use it a lot. The second is off-topic.

Comment: Saying 'we need to know about hyperboles' might be taking it too far.

Comment: @ Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 The mass usage is, of course, non-pluralisable. An instance is count (see RHKWebster's).

Comment: Hyperboles are iconic sections of rhetoric that help one to avoid circular reasoning and unnecessary ellipses.

Comment: Hyperboles are incredibly important and you NEED to learn them. Knowledge of hyperboles will definitely save your life sooner or later.

Comment: ... is an example of hyperbole.

Comment: @JohnLawler that's really bad. :-D

Comment: "There are plenty of people in this world using them without realizing it." That is precisely why we should be learning them.

Comment: People also use grammar without realizing it (you've been doing it probably since you were 3 years old), but it's still a good idea to learn about it. It's also good to learn about similes, metaphors, idioms, etc.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I always thought hyperbolas were man-eating! Or is that parabolas?

Comment: Ellipses are the ones you hafta watch out for; you could get deleted.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ah, so the parable of the talents was true after all then.

Comment: @tchrist Yes. Exactly. See ["Elliptical Conditionals and Hyperbolic Imperatives"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/conics.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperbole is the most important thing in the world. You can't possibly have an intelligent conversation without understanding hyperbole. You can't make it through breakfast without understanding hyperbole. Without hyperbole, all literature, if not civilization itself, would come to an end.

But okay seriously, you could ask this question about anything that someone might try to teach you, regarding language or any other subject. Why do I need to know about prepositions? Why do I need to know about subject/verb agreement? Why do I need to know about algebra? Etc.

Hyperbole is a tool of language that helps you to express yourself. The better you understand it, the more clearly you can say what you want to say, and understand what others say.